# What is the most accepted way to refer to the Filipino language (in Tagalog)?

Tags: localization, internationalization

The context is the top bar of a website that also has the names of other languages spelled out in their native script/letters.

Like this: English | Español | tiếng Việt | 汉语 | Filipino

Also, if you think any of the others above look wrong, please let me know. I'm looking for the standard accepted native form. I don't want to offend any volunteer translators on the open source project I'm doing design work for.

Comment: Stackoverflow is probably the wrong place for this kind of question. In your position I would try to ask some translators (for example at [proz](http://www.proz.com) ).

Comment: @Jenszcz thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filipino is quite right, you can check facebook's language setting it also listed Filipino there.

Just to add something, Tagalog is a dialect from which Philippines national language (which is Filipino) was based upon.

Comment: Thanks! I will stick with "Filipino" unless anybody objects or requests that I change it to "Tagalog"